# Android edit text italic issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a feature where users can select a text in an Edit text and make the text italic or bold by clicking buttons in a small toolbar. I wrote some code in android studio but there is an issue.

```
public void bold(EditText text){
        int start = text.getSelectionStart();
        int end = text.getSelectionEnd();
        CharacterStyle style = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text.getText().toString());
        sb.setSpan(style, start, end, 0);
        text.setText(sb);
    }
```

When user click bold button, it calls the **`bold()`** function and bolds the selected text.but if i change the selection and click italics, it italics the selected text but deletes the bold style i already applied to the edit text.

For example

> **exampleone** exampletwo (bolds the text)

But if click select exampletwo and click italic

it becomes

> exampleone *exampletwo*

I lost the style of the first word in the Edittext.

How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: You need to track the state of your text.

Answer (score -1):

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = newSpannableStringBuilder(bodyView.getText());

cs = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
ssb.setSpan(cs, start, end, 1);

cs = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
ssb.setSpan(cs, start, end, 1);
```

I think you should use same Spannablestringbuilder for bold and italic.
It works for me.